# Javascript: What's the difference between .call() and super()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

What's the difference between .call() and super()? Is super() just an es2015 thing? Or does .call() have more functionality?

Comment: Feels like comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- super() calls the constructor of the class you extened

  ```
  class Foo extends Bar {
    constructor() {
      super();  // calls Bar's constructor
    }
   }
  ```
- call is a generic function you can use with **any** function

  ```
  function a() { console.log(this); };
  function b() { console.log(this); };
  function c() { console.log(this}; };

  a.call("hello");
  b.call(123);
  c.call({});
  ```
- super knows which class you inherited from and automatically passes the correct `this`.

  ```
  class Foo extends Bar {
    constructor() {
      super();  // calls Bar's constructor
    }
  }
  ```
- call requires you to be explicit.

  ```
  class Foo extends Bar {
    constructor() {
      Bar.call(this);  // You had explicitly specify 'Bar' 
                       // and explicitly pass 'this'
    }
  }
  ```
- super lets you call functions on the parent implicitly

  ```
  class Bar {
    log() { 
      console.log("bar-log");
    }
  }

  class Foo extends Bar {
    log() {
      super.log();
    }
  }
  ```
- call requires you to be explicit

  ```
  class Bar {
    log() { 
      console.log("bar-log");
    }
  }

  class Foo extends Bar {
    log() {
      Bar.prototype.log.call(this);  // Explicitly reference bar's log function
                                     // and explicitly specify 'this'
    }
  }
  ```

I think you could argue `super` offers a subset of the functionality of `call`. Some might call it *syntactic sugar* meaning you can use `call` everywhere you can use `super`, super is just easier because it implicitly calls stuff from the class you extended/inherited from (technically the next thing up the prototype chain?) and because it implicitly passes `this` for you.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you relate `call` and `super` because of code like the following:

```
function Foo() {
   Bar.call(this)
}

class Foo extends Bar {
   constructor() {
      super()
   }
 }
```

In the case above, both examples do the same thing (call the constructor of `Bar` in the context of a new instance of `Foo`), but from there `super` and `call` differ greatly.

First off `super` is a key word, `call` is a method of `Function`'s prototype.

The `super` keyword can be used to call the parent classes constructor and methods. So, in addition to the examples above super can do this:

```
class Bar {
  constructor() {
    //...
  }

  bang() {
    console.log('bang')
  }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor() {
    super()
    //...
  }

  bang() {
    // call parents method in context of `this`
    super.bang()

    //...
  }
}
```

`call`, on the other hand, is a method of the `Function` class that allows a function to be invoked with an explicit value for the `this` variable. Consider the following function.

```
function baz() { console.log(this.bar) }
baz() // -> "undefined"
baz.call({ bar: 'foo' }) // -> "foo"
```

The above example is actually a little more nuanced. Unless in strict mode, `this` will be the global object (`global`, `window`). In strict mode, `this` is undefined, and our `baz` function will throw an error. With `call` we can explicitly set `this`, a very powerful feature.