# ReactJS: what is super() for in this case?

Tags: javascript, function, class, reactjs, constructor

I'm learning ReactJS. I figured that now the best way create a component is extending the class React.Component. My question is, what is this `super(props)` doing exactly?

I thought that it may be setting the basic props object, but if I delete the whole constructor method, it still works.

[image: props reactjs]

Comment: See [Javascript: What's the difference between .call() and super()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38034059/1529630), [what does super() do with any arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39822941/1529630) and probably there is a better duplicate.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/30571875/1048572

Comment: If you delete the whole constructor, the default constructor will pass all arguments through to `super(…)`

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Super calls constructor of parrent class and it's required in constructor of class that 'extends' from another class.

Comment: this questions relates to React behaviour, not `super` in general.